# How to determine which LOGFONT charset to use?

Tags: winapi, fonts, character-encoding, mfc

I have a text selection / specification dialog, where the user can specify the font from a list, set bold, italic, etc. I then use the info in a `LOGFONT` to create a `CFont` to subsequently use in a `CEdit` as a preview.

However, if the user picks a symbol font like Wingdings, the preview doesn't work correctly unless I set `LOGFONT::lfCharset` to `SYMBOL_CHARSET`. So, essentially given only a font name, how do I determine what the default charset should be (ie, how can I tell if I should us `SYMBOL_CHARSET`)?.

I've seen suggestions to use `GetTextMetrics()`, but that involves setting a font into a DC, and I haven't created the font yet, so...?

Comment: What has this to do with the tag c++?

Comment: Honestly? Am I misunderstanding the tagging system? I tagged this C++ and MFC to indicate the environment I'm working in, is it necessary to also mention that in the question?

Comment: @Kyudos From c++ tag info: _Use this tag for questions about code (to be) compiled with a C++ compiler._ so, where is the code that you are having problems to be compiled with it, or are behaving incorrectly?

Comment: How are you allowing the user to select a font?  If you use the [`ChooseFont()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646914(v=vs.85).aspx) standard dialog, it gives you a populated `LOGFONT` that you can then manipulate afterwards as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The font names are populated to a combo using a call to a third party API for my host environment. I'm essentially constructing the `LOGFONT` by hand.

Comment: @Kyudos If you use the Win32 API [`EnumFonts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-enumfontsw) function instead to populate the ComboBox yourself, you will be given a populated `LOGFONT` for each installed font. Save that info somewhere for later use when the user selects a font from the ComboBox.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks...that put me on the right track...I used `EnumFontFamiliesEx` to find the charsets for the given font, so see if they included `SYMBOL_CHARSET`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the name of the font, you can use [`EnumFontFamiliesEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-enumfontfamiliesexw) to see if that font exists for a particular charset.  You can call it once with `DEFAULT_CHARSET` and, if that doesn't work, call it again with `SYMBOL_CHARSET`.

That's a guess anyway.  I haven't had a chance to try it myself.